# Delete files iteratively in a directory

Tags: bash, ansible

I'm using ansible to copy files out of a docker container to a folder. I want to delete the ones not needed based on the version of container I'm downloading.  I'm not a scripter at all but I got as far as:

```
for i in `ls`; do if [[ $i < '6.1.0' ]]; then echo $i this_one; fi; done
```

In my ansible code it looks like this:

```
  - name: List files in folder
      ansible.builtin.shell: ls /tmp/sql/v{{ tversion }}/upgrade
      register: file_out
```

How can I take the output and delete files older than the version called out (in the above example anything older then 6.1.0)?

The file structure is actually `6.0.1_to_6.0.2.sql` and so on.

Comment: Your use of the term 'older' is ambiguous.

Comment: Older meaning say I have sql files that are named like:
1.0.0_to_1.0.1.sql, 1.0.1_to_1.0.2.sql, 1.0.2_to_1.0.3.sql al the way to 6.0.0_to_6.0.1.sql.  When I copy the files for a specific version it copies all of them when really all I need are the files that are for a specific version to to the latest. (say I upgrade someone to 6.2.0, I don't need all the older versions......just specifically the version they are currently at up to the version they are upgrading to).

Not sure if that makes any sense

Comment: *... it copies all of them* -- In that case, it will be helpful to know how you copy the files, and address this right there. than copy even the unnecessary files and then try to delete them later.

Comment: I'm using docker cp command after using the docker module to call the container from our private registry, then docker cp to grab the upgrade folder and then killing and removing the docker container with said scripts.  As you can see my scripting ability is non-existent.  Currently it copies all the files out.  I've got that automation down.  I'm just trying to figure out how go back and delete the files not needed based on the version of the container (which is in a var).  So for specific versions it will copy all and delete whats not needed

Answer (score 1):

For example, given the files

```sh
shell> tree test-482
test-482
├── 5.0.1_to_5.0.4.sql
├── 6.0.1_to_6.0.2.sql
└── 7.0.1_to_7.0.9.sql
```

Find the files

```yaml
    - find:
        path: test-482
        recurse: true
      register: result
```

gives the result

```yaml
  result.files|map(attribute='path')|list:
  - test-482/5.0.1_to_5.0.4.sql
  - test-482/6.0.1_to_6.0.2.sql
  - test-482/7.0.1_to_7.0.9.sql
```

Parse the attributes and create the dictionary

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        files_from_to: "{{ dict(_files|zip(_from_to)|list) }}"
      vars:
        _files: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
        _names: "{{ _files|map('basename')|map('splitext')|map('first')|list }}"
        _from_to: "{{ _names|map('regex_replace', _regex, _replace)|map('from_yaml')|list }}"
        _regex: "^(.*)_to_(.*)$"
        _replace: '{"from": "\1", "to": "\2"}'
```

gives

```yaml
  files_from_to:
    test-482/5.0.1_to_5.0.4.sql:
      from: 5.0.1
      to: 5.0.4
    test-482/6.0.1_to_6.0.2.sql:
      from: 6.0.1
      to: 6.0.2
    test-482/7.0.1_to_7.0.9.sql:
      from: 7.0.1
      to: 7.0.9
```

Use the test [*version*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#comparing-versions) to select the files, e.g.

```yaml
    - name: Anything higher then 6.1.0
      set_fact:
        files_del: "{{ files_from_to|dict2items|
                       selectattr('value.to', 'version', _version, 'gt')|
                       map(attribute='key')|list }}"
      vars:
        _version: '6.1.0'
```

gives

```yaml
  files_del:
  - test-482/7.0.1_to_7.0.9.sql
```

or,

```yaml
    - name: Anything lower then 6.0.2
      set_fact:
        files_del: "{{ files_from_to|dict2items|
                       selectattr('value.from', 'version', _version, 'lt')|
                       map(attribute='key')|list }}"
      vars:
        _version: '6.0.2'
```

gives

```yaml
  files_del:
  - test-482/5.0.1_to_5.0.4.sql
  - test-482/6.0.1_to_6.0.2.sql
```

---

Debug the dictionary step by step

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: _files
      vars:
        _files: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"

    - debug:
        var: _names
      vars:
        _files: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
        _names: "{{ _files|map('basename')|map('splitext')|map('first')|list }}"

    - debug:
        var: _from_to
      vars:
        _files: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
        _names: "{{ _files|map('basename')|map('splitext')|map('first')|list }}"
        _from_to: "{{ _names|map('regex_replace', _regex, _replace)|map('from_yaml')|list }}"
        _regex: "^(.*)_to_(.*)$"
        _replace: '{"from": "\1", "to": "\2"}'

    - debug:
        var: _files|zip(_from_to)|list
      vars:
        _files: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
        _names: "{{ _files|map('basename')|map('splitext')|map('first')|list }}"
        _from_to: "{{ _names|map('regex_replace', _regex, _replace)|map('from_yaml')|list }}"
        _regex: "^(.*)_to_(.*)$"
        _replace: '{"from": "\1", "to": "\2"}'
```

give

```yaml
  _files:
  - test-482/5.0.1_to_5.0.4.sql
  - test-482/6.0.1_to_6.0.2.sql
  - test-482/7.0.1_to_7.0.9.sql

  _names:
  - 5.0.1_to_5.0.4
  - 6.0.1_to_6.0.2
  - 7.0.1_to_7.0.9

  _from_to:
  - from: 5.0.1
    to: 5.0.4
  - from: 6.0.1
    to: 6.0.2
  - from: 7.0.1
    to: 7.0.9

  _files|zip(_from_to)|list:
  - - test-482/5.0.1_to_5.0.4.sql
    - from: 5.0.1
      to: 5.0.4
  - - test-482/6.0.1_to_6.0.2.sql
    - from: 6.0.1
      to: 6.0.2
  - - test-482/7.0.1_to_7.0.9.sql
    - from: 7.0.1
      to: 7.0.9
```

---

Debug the selection step by step

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ files_from_to|dict2items }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ files_from_to|dict2items|
                 selectattr('value.to', 'version', _version, 'gt') }}"
      vars:
        _version: '6.1.0'

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ files_from_to|dict2items|
                 selectattr('value.to', 'version', _version, 'gt')|
                 map(attribute='key')|list }}"
      vars:
        _version: '6.1.0'
```

give

```yaml
  msg:
  - key: test-482/5.0.1_to_5.0.4.sql
    value:
      from: 5.0.1
      to: 5.0.4
  - key: test-482/6.0.1_to_6.0.2.sql
    value:
      from: 6.0.1
      to: 6.0.2
  - key: test-482/7.0.1_to_7.0.9.sql
    value:
      from: 7.0.1
      to: 7.0.9

  msg:
  - key: test-482/7.0.1_to_7.0.9.sql
    value:
      from: 7.0.1
      to: 7.0.9

  msg:
  - test-482/7.0.1_to_7.0.9.sql
```

Comment: Comments are not for extensive discussion nor providing needed info to answer your question and especially not to paste large portions of code. Either this is still related to the original problem and you edit your question, or it is a totally new issue and you ask a new one.

Comment: It looks closed to me
```files_from_to: "{{ dict(_files|zip(_from_to)|list) }}"```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged `bash`, here's one way to do it.

The Linux [find command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) supports `-regex` for matching file names, and also supports deleting files. So, we can use them to find and delete files without having to iterate.

```
# Find all files up to 6.0.0, and delete them
find . -type f -regex '\.\/[1-5]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]_to_[1-5]\.[0-9]\.[0-9].sql' -delete

# Find files of 6.0 series (excluding anything above 6.1)
find . -type f -regex '\.\/6\.0\.[0-9]_to_6\.0\.[0-9].sql' -delete
```

There might be a more efficient way to find and delete files in one stroke, but we can use this in an Ansible task:

```yaml
    - shell:
        cmd: |
          find . -type f -regex '\.\/[1-5]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]_to_[1-5]\.[0-9]\.[0-9].sql' -delete
          find . -type f -regex '\.\/6\.0\.[0-9]_to_6\.0\.[0-9].sql' -delete
        chdir: path/to/sql
```